# Synonym for Fakability

Tags: single-word-requests

*Fakability* is **not an actual word**. I came up with it to explain what I am looking for - a word that aptly describes something that can be easily faked. For example,

> The *fakability* of this device is so high that we can never be sure if
>   the sample we are holding came from the original source.

you see, there is a technical context here,

> Those parameters have high *fakability*, you must double check their
>   values as a script kiddie can easily simulate them.

Comment: For your specific example, _"Those parameters are **easily spoofed**,..."_?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin The problem is, in my genre of writing (cyber-security), *spoof* actually has a strong technical meaning. By using *spoof*, I run into the chance of confusing an expert in my area. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoofing_attack
Here I am looking at just faking some values, say, to avoid detection, not a whole spoofing attack.

Comment: I'll ask you for your technical meaning for _spoof_, then, as in my field (IT, not exclusively cybersecurity), it is also jargon, and seems quite appropriate here. Compare wiki's 'email spoofing' on the page you linked to.

Comment: Having said that, except in the most formal writing, I'd bet on _fakability_ being understood and accepted without any hesitation.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin So spoofing a situation in which a person or program successfully masquerades as another by falsifying data, to gain an illegitimate advantage. While the general definition seems apt, the idea is one generally spoofs packets, TCP/IP protocols etc. I am looking at spoofing some values - churned out by a machine or an algorithm. For example, the virus Stuxnet fed fake values to a certain PLC controller - this will never be termed as spoofing, but rather *injection*.

Comment: OK, so you're limiting _spoof_ to specifically an attack context, whereas I don't.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Exactly!

Comment: I would consider what Stuxnet was doing as 'spoofing'; it was spoofing whatever device normally sent data to the PLCs that Stuxnet attacked.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin True, but somehow we always use the word injection here:https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/stuxnet-worm-revealed-installation-injection-and-mitigation/
or this:
https://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/exploring-stuxnet-s-plc-infection-process

Comment: However, I think the spelling suggested below is apt with an already-in-use example, so I am just going with fakeable.

Comment: @Jishan: I don't believe that 'spoof' is as narrowly defined as you seem to think. I will accept that it *usually* is used in reference to spoofing ones identity, generally with falsified TCP/IP packets, however my understanding is that other data can also be spoofed. This doesn't however mean that it's the best word for you.

Comment: @3D1T0R True. My reluctance to use spoof was because I already have a spoof scenario in my paper - so I was strongly looking at a different word.

Comment: *Mimicablility.*

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fakeable 'nuf said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would spell it fakeability but both forms exist, even if they are rare. The word seems to be quite commonly used in the computer security field.

For example:

[On the Specification of Secure Channels](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/gavin.lowe/Papers/channels.pdf)

> Recall that non-confidential, non-redirectable, **fakeable** channels can simulate message redirection by learning messages and faking them ...

[Formal Aspects in Security and Trust: 6th International Workshop, FAST 2009](https://books.google.it/books?id=SSqqCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA239&ots=ah7MNSlUcu&dq=%22fakable%22%20definition&pg=PA240#v=onepage&q=%22fakable%22)

> If a channel is non-fakable ...

There also uses relating to crime scene evidence, etc.

Comment: Incidentally, my field IS cybersecurity. I guess then my usage will be apt.  Thanks for the correct spelling.

Comment: Can you provide Marriam Webster or Oxford Dictionary reference supporting your argument?

Comment: @Looper No. The word isn’t in the online versions.

Comment: @JamesRandom it is just a made up word.

Comment: @Looper All words are "made up". Many, as in this case, using the rules of English morphology and phonology. The word is constructed in standard ways from existing morphemes. Its meaning is transparent, based on the bound morpheme suffixes. It is not frequently used enough to appear in some dictionaries. You will find that is true of many words. Both spellings do occur in Wiktionary: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fakable (but perhaps you think that is a made up website).

Comment: Exactly! you either need a standard source to support your answer or update your answer saying that it is not a part of standard source. I can get you thousands of words from Urban Dictionary, but those words are not academically accepted. You can misguide OP with your answer, though I know it is not your intension.

Comment: @Looper I quoted a couple of academic sources that use the word. The idea that you cannot use a word if it is not in a dictionary is ludicrous. If everyone followed that rule, there would never be any new words!